# How to include the abstract in HTML output

Tags: pandoc

A simple example with `pandoc` 2.19.2:

```
$ cat test.md
---
title: An Example
author: Luís
language: en-IE

abstract: |

  This is my abstract.
---

# Intro

Some text.

# Conclusion

More text.

$ pandoc -o test.html test.md

$ cat test.html
<h1 id="intro">Intro</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<h1 id="conclusion">Conclusion</h1>
<p>More text.</p>
```

The abstract does not appear in the HTML output, but in other formats it does (e.g. PDF). Is any extra parameter necessary for HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc 2.17 and later support this by default. A custom template has to be used for older pandoc versions. E.g., download the updated [`defaults.html5` template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/pandoc/master/data/templates/default.html5) and pass it to pandoc via

```
pandoc --template=/path/to/defaults.html5
```

Comment: This works, but I am using version 2.19, apparently it is not default behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a file `templates/defaults.html5` in your pandoc data directory? That would explain it.

Comment: I added it to the user templates folder. Which would be the data folder?

Comment: I meant the "user data directory", which pandoc outputs when called with `pandoc -v`. Pandoc will first check for files in that folder before falling back to the built-in templates.

Comment: `pandoc -v` reports the data directory as `$HOME/.local/share/pandoc`. There are no HTML files in that folder.